# Passing data between angularjs modues/controllers

Tags: angularjs, service, controller

So I have two modules each one with one with its own controller and I need to pass an object between them, I seen this can be done with a service, I tried some stuff but I keep getting an "$injector" error in the second module/controller. Please help fix this.
This is my first module/controller with its service:

```
var appIndex = angular.module("AppIndex", ['datatables', 'datatables.bootstrap', 'ui.select']);
appIndex.service('sharedData', function () {
    this.data = {};
    this.setData = function (newData) {
        this.data = newData;
        return this.data;
    };
    this.getData = function () {
        return this.data;
    };
});
appIndex.controller("IndexController", function ($scope, $http, $window, sharedData) {
    sharedData.setData($scope.referencia);
});
```

And this is my second module/controller:

```
var appCna = angular.module("AppCna", ['ui.select', 'AppIndex']);
appCna.controller("CnaController", function ($scope, $http, $window, sharedData) {
    $scope.referencia = sharedData.getData();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call **`setData`** in your first controller

```
appIndex.controller("IndexController", function ($scope, $http, $window, sharedData) {
    sharedData.setData($scope.referencia);
});
```

Comment: Ok i already did that but i keep getting this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: you need to check if you have added all the references in index.html

Comment: sorry, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: whatever the references ( javascript files ) needed for your dependencies such as datatables etc

Comment: OH! yes i did that, the index file is fine, i checked if the service is working by printing the $scope.reference object and it works, the error appears in the second page(cna.html), it seems im injecting the index.js or it service wrong the cns.js file

Comment: well that could be the issue, otherwise code looks fine

Comment: I mean when you need to use a service declared in a different module, you inject that module as a dependency, then inject the service in your controller right?

Comment: I had to inject in the cna.js file all the dependencies of index.js file(this contains the service declaration), and then it did not threw any errors, but still didnt worked, so Im thinking now about using the localStorage function instead, and giving up on the service :(    But thanks so much any way for your time and attention

Answer (score 0):

So in the end I finally stop trying to use a service to my purpose of passing an object between two modules and what I did was to use the LocalStorage function.